# hsqldb not supporting columnDefinition attribute for the column

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, hsqldb, hibernate-annotations

I already had hsql db for testing and I added a couple of tables to that.

I updated .dtd and .xml files properly but was unable to run junits as "NoSuchTableException" was being thrown from dbunit test cases.

In the DAO class I added following property for the culprit table.

```
@Column(name = "keyword_id", columnDefinition = "int REFERENCES master_keyword(keyword_id)")
```

Once I removed columnDefinition attribute, junit worked fine. I understand that columnDefinition is database specific, does that mean, we should not use this while running junits?

I spent a lot of time on this. Problem is resolved but any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

If your unit tests use the annotations to automatically create the database tables, then obviously the `columnDefinition` attribute is taken into account: that's its purpose.

So if you have database-specific stuff, for another database than the one you're using, in the column definition, then obviously it won't work.

It looks like you want to define a foreign key constraint here. Why don't you use a OneToOne or ManyToOne association then?

Comment: I want to avoid that constraint from the code (because of a reason), I just wanted to have  a definition here and that constraint at the table itself.

It works fine in devo/prod but junits fail.